# Генерация уникального хеша - [a-zA-Z0-9]

Tags: php, база-данных, алгоритм

генерирую уникальный токен следующим образом:

беру из базы следующий `ID` и преобразовываю его... как теперь из этого преобразованного числа получить строку подобную - `cAdfQ` - где присутствуют верхний и нижний регистр? как это делают крупные проекты коротких ссылок, youtube, миллион строк в бд, и все же сохраняется уникальность

Comment: [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID)?

Comment: Предположим у на ограничение на длину этой строки 5 символов. В строке могут быть большие и маленькие латинские буквы и цифры. Итого 62 символа, на кодирование которых уходит 6 бит. Значит в 5 символах можно закодировать 30 бит. - это около 1 миллиарда значений. Значит берем 4х байтное уникальное число не превышающее 1 млрд. забираем из него по 6 бит из них кодируем символ

Answer (score 1):

Base16 / Base32 / Base64 уже смотрели?
Base64 с парой дополнительных символов - A-Z,a-z,0-9, +, /, =
есть версия под URL, с заменой спецсимволов на более безобидные _,-
Я бы вообще предложил в HEX A-F, 0-9 конвертить или просто использовать md5/sha-512 и т.д.

Comment: Есть Base58, где только буквы и цифры без 0,1,O,l

Comment: но "=" еще остаётся, так что лучше уж Base16

Comment: = - не обязательно. Можно так изменить алгоритм, чтобы его не было. Оно вообще для выравнивания и никакой информации о данных не хранит.